# Is there a way to work past a stream in functional fashion?

Tags: java, java-stream, reactive-streams

In a method, my code accesses a database and returns a Flux of data from the source. Flux is a stream similar to the Java Stream API. The query may or may not return any objects since they may not match the predicate. Whats the functional way of handling this so that a null pointer exception can be avoided?

I've worked around creating a reference variable to hold on to the semi-processed stream and depending on whether there are any elements or not, go ahead with the processing.

```
Flux<SomeObject> objects = dbConn.getObjects(QUERY);
Optional<SomeObject> test = objects.toStream().findFirst();
if(test.is.not.empty){
    objects.do_rest_of_processing();
}
```

This is problematic when I wish to chain everything together in a bigger implementation. Is there a piece I'm missing here so that I can achieve something similar?

Comment: What can be `null` in this case?

Comment: The usual functional way is to use `Optional`'s `ifPresent` or the equivalent methods on other APIs. With `Flux` (assuming this is Reactive Streams), you just use it normally, and if it's empty, the subscribers never get invoked.

Comment: @chrylis this may not always be a part of a "subscribe". What if it's a kind of a part of the invocation of something like flatMap() or concatMap()?

Comment: @ayushprashar Irrespective of what operation is being performed on a `Flux`, behaviour is same. Besides, the flux is not actually invoked until there are `subscriber`(s) consuming it. Have you actually tried to run the code with an empty flux, are you running into errors?

Comment: @Sindbad90 You're factually correct but yes I'm getting the NPE and I'll explain better now. I'm flatmapping into a stream, under which there's a function which returns another stream using the flatmapped value as a parameter. That stream may be null and I'm not subscribing there. I subscribe after another few operations I perform on that stream. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It would help if you could show some code that demonstrates how you're creating the other stream. Ideally, you would use `Flux.empty()` to represent a stream/flux with no elements, instead of returning `null`

Comment: Actually, you don't need any checking, Both Flux<T> and Mono<T> in reactive streams are lazy so if the Flux is empty it won't run the processing at all.